# Controller Class Not Found

Tags: php, symfony

Weirdest thing on my symfony 2 project, just added a new controller as I normally would, setup the routing and for some reason it just won't work...

src/AppBundle/Controller/SupplierController.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
// omitted all necessary use statements, but they are normally here... 

class SupplierController extends Controller
{
    public function signUpAction(Request $request)
    {
        $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
            ->add('fname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'First Name'))
            ->add('lname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Last Name'))
            ->add('company', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('phone', NumberType::class, array('label' => 'Tel. No.'))
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('receiveUpdates', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // data is an array with "name", "email", and "message" keys
            $data = $form->getData();
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Suppliers:SignUp:_form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

}
```

app/config/routing.yml:

```
// other routes omitted... 

supplier_sign_up:
    path: /supplier/register
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Supplier:signUp
```

Run the page:

```
The _controller value "AppBundle:Supplier:signUp" maps to a
"AppBundle\Controller\SupplierController" class, but this class was not
found. Create this class or check the spelling of the class and its
namespace.
```

Very strange ey? The route recognises the controller, the namespacing is correct, checked spelling etc. Can't work it out... any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: could it be a permission issue, just a shot in the dark.

Comment: try to remove/readd the spaces in this line `class SupplierController extends Controller`. I've had a couple of IDEs add some weird space instead of a normal one (seemingly on random) which messed up the naming for the word next to the "bad" space

Comment: Not a permission issue, as other controllers work fine, just checked the permissions for the every Controller and they are all the same. Tried your fix @JimL unfortunately no dice...

Comment: @UUakeUp, Can you show your `namespace` of `SupplierController`

Comment: Just to confirm, you have other properly working controllers in the same directory?  If so, double check your controller file name for spelling and control chars.  Maybe you have ei instead of ie?

Comment: Clearing cache seems to help this sometimes.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kimmi6 src is in project root. @Cerad Yeah, all the other controllers are functioning fine, I'm starting to think it may be a sylius issue. Pretty sure names are correct.

Comment: @ASOlivieri I tried : (

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be a Sylius issue, basically due to the way Sylius works with symfony I had to configure my form as a sylius resource and call it via a service